# Scrapy returning single item from selector list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get data of all the Amazon bestseller and to process that i have used the scrapy, i am able to get the whole selector list of data yet while iterating over the data list the result is still returning only single data item.

```
    def parse_page(self, response):

        product_data = response.xpath("//div[@id='gridItemRoot']") #THIS RETURNS A SELECTOR LIST

        for data in product_data:
            product_name = data.xpath("//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-mini _cDEzb_noop_3Xbw5']//img/@alt").get()
            product_rank = data.xpath("//span[@class='zg-bdg-text']/text()").get()
            
         # It only generates a single result
            yield {
                "name": product_name,
                "rank": product_rank
            }
```

i tried without iterating over a selectorlist rather passing selector directly to the method and yielding result but that also returned a single element.

```
    def parse_page(self, response):
   
      
   # in previous applications all the results were scraped without iterating over any selectorlist just like following

        product_name = response.xpath("//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-mini _cDEzb_noop_3Xbw5']//img/@alt").get()
        product_rank = response.xpath("//span[@class='zg-bdg-text']/text()").get()
       
 
        yield {
            "name": product_name,
            "rank": product_rank
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use relative xpath expressions.

```
    def parse_page(self, response):

        product_data = response.xpath("//div[@id='gridItemRoot']") #THIS RETURNS A SELECTOR LIST

        for data in product_data:
            product_name = data.xpath(".//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-mini _cDEzb_noop_3Xbw5']//img/@alt").get()
            product_rank = data.xpath(".//span[@class='zg-bdg-text']/text()").get()
            
         # It only generates a single result
            yield {
                "name": product_name,
                "rank": product_rank
            }
```

Without the `.` at the beginning of the xpath expression it will always grab the first match relative to the root element, which will always be the same element for every iteration.